# Cannot run Flutter Get Started. Project 'app' not found in root project 'myapp'

Tags: android, gradle, flutter

*Note. I can find many question with similar titles but none of them are in the same context and neither their proposed solutions have worked for me.*

I am trying get started with Flutter following the official tutorial. (https://flutter.io/get-started/test-drive/#terminal)

When I try to run

```
flutter run
```

The process hangs on 'Resolving Dependencies'

```
bruno@bruno-Latitude-E5430-non-vPro ~/Projects/myapp $ flutter run
Using hardware rendering with device Android SDK built for x86. If you get graphics artifacts, consider enabling software rendering with "--enable-software-rendering".
Launching lib/main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
Initializing gradle...                                       0.7s
Resolving dependencies...                                       -^C
bruno@bruno-Latitude-E5430-non-vPro ~/Projects/myapp $
```

So, I tried to run with '-v'

```
flutter run -v
```

And the process hangs on '[        ] [android/] /home/bruno/Projects/myapp/android/gradlew app:properties'

```
bruno@bruno-Latitude-E5430-non-vPro ~/Projects/myapp $ flutter run -v
[  +29 ms] [/home/bruno/development/flutter/] git rev-parse --abbrev-ref --symbolic @{u}
[  +31 ms] Exit code 0 from: git rev-parse --abbrev-ref --symbolic @{u}
[        ] origin/beta
[        ] [/home/bruno/development/flutter/] git rev-parse --abbrev-    ref HEAD
[   +6 ms] Exit code 0 from: git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
[        ] beta
[        ] [/home/bruno/development/flutter/] git ls-remote --get-url     origin
[   +5 ms] Exit code 0 from: git ls-remote --get-url origin
[        ] https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
[        ] [/home/bruno/development/flutter/] git log -n 1 --    pretty=format:%H
[   +6 ms] Exit code 0 from: git log -n 1 --pretty=format:%H
[        ] c7ea3ca377e909469c68f2ab878a5bc53d3cf66b
[        ] [/home/bruno/development/flutter/] git log -n 1 --pretty=format:%ar
[   +8 ms] Exit code 0 from: git log -n 1 --pretty=format:%ar
[        ] 7 weeks ago
[        ] [/home/bruno/development/flutter/] git describe --match v*.*.* --first-parent --long --tags
[   +6 ms] Exit code 0 from: git describe --match v*.*.* --first-    parent --long --tags
[        ] v0.5.1-0-gc7ea3ca
[ +141 ms] /home/bruno/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb devices -l
[   +6 ms] Exit code 0 from: /home/bruno/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb devices -l
[        ] List of devices attached
           emulator-5554          device product:sdk_google_phone_x86         model:Android_SDK_built_for_x86 device:generic_x86 transport_id:3
[ +161 ms] /home/bruno/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-5554 shell getprop
[  +32 ms] ro.hardware = ranchu
[  +16 ms] Using hardware rendering with device Android SDK built for x86. If you get graphics artifacts, consider enabling software rendering with "--enable-software-rendering".
[ +608 ms] Launching lib/main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
[   +5 ms] Initializing gradle...
[   +7 ms] Using gradle from     /home/bruno/Projects/myapp/android/gradlew.
[  +56 ms] /home/bruno/Projects/myapp/android/gradlew -v
[ +632 ms] 
                   ------------------------------------------------------------
                   Gradle 4.1
                   ------------------------------------------------------------

                   Build time:   2017-08-07 14:38:48 UTC
                   Revision:     941559e020f6c357ebb08d5c67acdb858a3defc2

                   Groovy:       2.4.11
                   Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.6 compiled on June 29 2015
                   JVM:          1.8.0_152-release (JetBrains s.r.o 25.152-b01)
                   OS:           Linux 4.13.0-45-generic amd64
[   +2 ms] Resolving dependencies...
[        ] [android/] /home/bruno/Projects/myapp/android/gradlew app:properties
```

The, I tried to run 'android/gradlew app:properties' directly from terminal:

and got this error:

```
bruno@bruno-Latitude-E5430-non-vPro ~/Projects/myapp $ android/gradlew app:properties

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Project 'app' not found in root project 'myapp'.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 0s
```

**What goes wrong?????**

```
bruno@bruno-Latitude-E5430-non-vPro ~/Projects/myapp $ tree
.
├── android
│   ├── app
│   │   ├── build.gradle
│   │   └── src
│   │       └── main
│   │           ├── AndroidManifest.xml
│   │           ├── java
│   │           │   ├── com
│   │           │   │   └── example
│   │           │   │       └── myapp
│   │           │   │           └── MainActivity.java
│   │           │   └── io
│   │           │       └── flutter
│   │           │           └── plugins
│   │           │               └── GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java
│   │           └── res
│   │               ├── drawable
│   │               │   └── launch_background.xml
│   │               ├── mipmap-hdpi
│   │               │   └── ic_launcher.png
│   │               ├── mipmap-mdpi
│   │               │   └── ic_launcher.png
│   │               ├── mipmap-xhdpi
│   │               │   └── ic_launcher.png
│   │               ├── mipmap-xxhdpi
│   │               │   └── ic_launcher.png
│   │               ├── mipmap-xxxhdpi
│   │               │   └── ic_launcher.png
│   │               └── values
│   │                   └── styles.xml
│   ├── build.gradle
│   ├── gradle
│   │   └── wrapper
│   │       ├── gradle-wrapper.jar
│   │       └── gradle-wrapper.properties
│   ├── gradle.properties
│   ├── gradlew
│   ├── gradlew.bat
│   ├── local.properties
│   └── settings.gradle
├── ios
│   ├── Flutter
│   │   ├── AppFrameworkInfo.plist
│   │   ├── Debug.xcconfig
│   │   ├── Generated.xcconfig
│   │   └── Release.xcconfig
│   ├── Runner
│   │   ├── AppDelegate.h
│   │   ├── AppDelegate.m
│   │   ├── Assets.xcassets
│   │   │   ├── AppIcon.appiconset
│   │   │   │   ├── Contents.json
│   │   │   │   ├── Icon-App-1024x1024@1x.png
│   │   │   │   ├── Icon-App-20x20@1x.png
│   │   │   │   ├── Icon-App-20x20@2x.png
│   │   │   │   ├── Icon-App-20x20@3x.png
│   │   │   │   ├── Icon-App-29x29@1x.png
│   │   │   │   ├── Icon-App-29x29@2x.png
│   │   │   │   ├── Icon-App-29x29@3x.png
│   │   │   │   ├── Icon-App-40x40@1x.png
│   │   │   │   ├── Icon-App-40x40@2x.png
│   │   │   │   ├── Icon-App-40x40@3x.png
│   │   │   │   ├── Icon-App-60x60@2x.png
│   │   │   │   ├── Icon-App-60x60@3x.png
│   │   │   │   ├── Icon-App-76x76@1x.png
│   │   │   │   ├── Icon-App-76x76@2x.png
│   │   │   │   └── Icon-App-83.5x83.5@2x.png
│   │   │   └── LaunchImage.imageset
│   │   │       ├── Contents.json
│   │   │       ├── LaunchImage@2x.png
│   │   │       ├── LaunchImage@3x.png
│   │   │       ├── LaunchImage.png
│   │   │       └── README.md
│   │   ├── Base.lproj
│   │   │   ├── LaunchScreen.storyboard
│   │   │   └── Main.storyboard
│   │   ├── GeneratedPluginRegistrant.h
│   │   ├── GeneratedPluginRegistrant.m
│   │   ├── Info.plist
│   │   └── main.m
│   ├── Runner.xcodeproj
│   │   ├── project.pbxproj
│   │   ├── project.xcworkspace
│   │   │   └── contents.xcworkspacedata
│   │   └── xcshareddata
│   │       └── xcschemes
│   │           └── Runner.xcscheme
│   └── Runner.xcworkspace
│       └── contents.xcworkspacedata
├── lib
│   └── main.dart
├── myapp_android.iml
├── myapp.iml
├── pubspec.lock
├── pubspec.yaml
├── README.md
└── test
    └── widget_test.dart

35 directories, 63 files
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [gradlew docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html): *"The recommended way to execute any Gradle build is with the help of the Gradle Wrapper (in short just “Wrapper”). The Wrapper is a script that invokes a declared version of Gradle, **downloading it beforehand if necessary**."*

So, my guess is that the process is not hanging, it's just taking a long time to finish. I'd check the network activity to see if something is being downloaded.

PS: the error you got when running the gradlew command manually isn't an issue, if you go into the android directory, it should work.

Comment: _"if you go into the android directory, it should work."_

Comment: _"if you go into the android directory, it should work."_


`bruno@bruno-Latitude-E5430-non-vPro ~/Projects/myapp/android $ gradlew app:properties
No command 'gradlew' found, did you mean:
 Command 'gradle' from package 'gradle' (universe)
gradlew: command not found`


But problably you are right about the download. In my first attempt I waited about 6 hours and it did not finish. But I beleave my connection was in trouble that time because now it is downloading. I will wait and give the results latter.

Comment: Try`./gradlew app:properties`.

Answer (score 1):

I hit this problem.  As it turned out, I was missing `key.properties` in the `android/` folder of my Android Studio project.

The exact error I got was:

```
* Error running Gradle:
ProcessException: Process "/Users/fakeuser/git/fakereponame/android/gradlew" exited abnormally:

  Command: /Users/fakeuser/git/fakereponame/android/gradlew app:properties

Finished with error: Please review your Gradle project setup in the android/ folder.
```

This error came up because my `android/app/build.gradle` has this block of code, which is pulled from the flutter tutorial.  It does a file check for `key.properties`, but does not give a very descriptive error:

```
def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
    keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Run `flutter doctor`.

If everything looks fine there, unfortunately it looks like your environment have a mysterious problem.

I would start by reviewing your PATH, exports, etc.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was getting this error because I was missing the `settings.gradle` file in the `android` folder. Adding a `setting.gradle` file containing the following code solved it for me:

```
include ':app'

def localPropertiesFile = new File(rootProject.projectDir, "local.properties")
def properties = new Properties()

assert localPropertiesFile.exists()
localPropertiesFile.withReader("UTF-8") { reader -> properties.load(reader) }

def flutterSdkPath = properties.getProperty("flutter.sdk")
assert flutterSdkPath != null, "flutter.sdk not set in local.properties"
apply from: "$flutterSdkPath/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/app_plugin_loader.gradle"
```